# PHP random choice of results with a limit

Tags: php

I have a collection of files (each file containing a grammar exercise), and a table in my DB where each file is described according to its topic, tense and type.

I have a form where I can select the topic, tense and type I need.
Using the following PHP script, I can retrieve the file(s) I searched for. The maximum number of retrieved exercises corresponds to the value of $limit.

Everything works fine, but what I can't do is to shuffle all the retrieved exercises and return them at random. As it is, the script browses the DB top-down, retrieves the exercises but it stops when it reaches the amount of $limit. As a consequence, the exercises stored at the bottom of the table in the DB, are never retrieved.

Do you have any ideas about how to shuffle all the candidate files and then output n of them, where n=$limit?

```
if(isset($_POST['limit'], $_POST['topic'], $_POST['tense'], $_POST['type']))
{
    $counter = 0;
    $limit = intval($_POST['limit']);
    $result = '';
    foreach ($_POST['topic'] as $key_topic => $value_topic)
    {
            foreach ($_POST['tense'] as $key_tense => $value_tense)
        {
            foreach ($_POST['type'] as $key_type => $value_type)
            {
               $q_to_te_ty = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE topic = '".$value_topic."' AND tense = '".$value_tense."' AND type = '".$value_type."' ORDER BY RAND()";              
               $qu_to_te_ty = mysql_query($q_to_te_ty);
               while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($qu_to_te_ty) and ($counter < $limit))
                             {
                                     $result = $rows['file'];
                                     readfile("files/$result");
                     echo "----------------------------------------"."\n"."\n";
                     $counter++;
                             }
            }
        }
    }
    if(!$result)
      {
          echo "SORRY. There are no exercises in the database which match your search."."\n"."Please try selecting different values.";
      }
}
else
{
    echo "ERROR: You forgot to check something."."\n"."Please select at least one type, topic and tense value. And don't forget to set a number of exercises.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Doing a foreach on each of the $_POST variables is a bit counter intuitive, you are not sanitizing inputs, and you use deprecated PHP functions, but besides that, you are missing your actual LIMIT clause. See if that helps if you add the LIMIT clause accordingly.

Comment: All my inputs (limit, topic, tense, type) are fed through a form (multiple selection) with fixed values. The users do not type in anything. They just choose what they need. Regarding the limit, it is set, and the script actually stops retrieving when $limit value is reached. I just need a strategy to really shuffle all the candidates before the output.

Comment: Ale, your code above does not reflect that you have a limit in place. in the query. You have it in a place I did not expect it. I would say add a "LIMIT" clause in your query itself. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Oh, regarding input sanitation, even if your users do not enter anything in plain text, a hacker can use your site and intercept the post values and modify them to his/her bidding. Sanitation is ALWAYS required when dealing with user input - whether by select box or plain text fields.

Comment: Kobus, thanks for your feedback. I actually ignored completely the possibility of having the website hacked. I'll sanitize the inputs.

Comment: Pleasure, Ale, let me know if your problem is solved when using a LIMIT clause within the MySQL query.

Comment: I'll look into it as soon as I am back home from holidays :-) thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use MySQL's `RAND()` function:

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT $limit
```

or some such.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to limit the output after having retrieved all the candidates.
If I put a LIMIT statement in my query (as you suggested), the output gets messy (there are three FOREACH loops on top of that...)

I guess I need to put all the candidates into an array and SHUFFLE it before getting my output (with a LIMIT statement).
Frankly, I can't figure out how.